# Have a sub-query return multiple fields in SQL Server 2008r2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am doing some reporting in Delphi and I require all of the invoice header information to be returned in a single query.  The problem is that 4 fields I need for the header can come from 4 different places depending on a value in the master table.  I have the following (which doesn't work) as an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
select t.ID, t.TRANSACTIONNUMBER, t.TRANSACTIONDATE,
  a.ABBREVIATION, a.NAME, d.LINE1, d.LINE2, d.LINE3,
  d.CITY, d.[STATE], d.ZIPCODE, tl.NAME COUNTRYNAME,
  b.NAME BROKERNAME, t.ORIGIN, t.TRANSACTIONTYPE,
  t.REFERENCESID, t.POSTED, t.DELETED, t.PROFORMA,
  t.REMARKS, abs(t.AMOUNT) AMOUNT, c.CONVERSIONRATE,
  c.ABBREVIATION CURRENCYABBR,
  case t.ORIGIN 
    when 25 then (select VESSELID, VOYAGENUMBER, ARRIVALTIME, DEPARTURETIME from HMLOG where (ID = t.REFERENCESID))
    when 26 then (select VESSELID, VOYAGENUMBER, ARRIVALTIME, DEPARTURETIME from HMLOG where (ID in (SELECT HMLOGID FROM CARGO_BOL WHERE ID = t.REFERENCESID)))
    when 27 then (select VESSELID, VOYAGENUMBER, ARRIVALTIME, DEPARTURETIME from HMLOG where (ID in (SELECT HMLOGOUTID FROM CONTAINERLOG  WHERE ID = t.REFERENCESID)))
    when 28 then (select null VESSELID, null VOYAGENUMBER, null ARRIVALTIME, null DEPARTURETIME)
  end    
from [TRAN] t join
     ACCOUNTS a on (t.ACCOUNTID = a.id) join
     [ADDRESS] d on (t.MAILINGID = d.id) left join
     ACCOUNTS b on (t.BRACCOUNTID = b.ID) join
     TYPES_LIST tl on (d.COUNTRY = tl.ID) join
     CURRENCY c on (t.ENTEREDCURRENCY = c.ID)
where (t.ID = 269017)
```

The issue is with the sub-queries in the case statement.  Does anyone have any elegant way of doing this?

Update:

I actually came up with the following which seems to work:

```
select t.ID, t.TRANSACTIONNUMBER, t.TRANSACTIONDATE,
  a.ABBREVIATION, a.NAME, d.LINE1, d.LINE2, d.LINE3,
  d.CITY, d.[STATE], d.ZIPCODE, tl.NAME COUNTRYNAME,
  b.NAME BROKERNAME, t.ORIGIN, t.TRANSACTIONTYPE,
  t.REFERENCESID, t.POSTED, t.DELETED, t.PROFORMA,
  t.REMARKS, abs(t.AMOUNT) AMOUNT, c.CONVERSIONRATE,
  c.ABBREVIATION CURRENCYABBR,
  case t.ORIGIN when 25 then har.VESSELID when 26 then hbl.VESSELID when 27 then hcl.VESSELID when 28 then null end VESSELID,
  case t.ORIGIN when 25 then va.VESSELNAME when 26 then vb.VESSELNAME when 27 then vc.VESSELNAME when 28 then null end VESSELNAME,
  case t.ORIGIN when 25 then har.VOYAGENUMBER when 26 then hbl.VOYAGENUMBER when 27 then hcl.VOYAGENUMBER when 28 then null end VOYAGENUMBER,
  case t.ORIGIN when 25 then har.ARRIVALTIME when 26 then hbl.ARRIVALTIME when 27 then hcl.ARRIVALTIME when 28 then null end ARRIVALTIME,
  case t.ORIGIN when 25 then har.DEPARTURETIME when 26 then hbl.DEPARTURETIME when 27 then hcl.DEPARTURETIME when 28 then null end DEPARTURETIME
from [TRAN] t join
     ACCOUNTS a on (t.ACCOUNTID = a.id) join
     [ADDRESS] d on (t.MAILINGID = d.id) left join
     ACCOUNTS b on (t.BRACCOUNTID = b.ID) join
     TYPES_LIST tl on (d.COUNTRY = tl.ID) join
     CURRENCY c on (t.ENTEREDCURRENCY = c.ID) left join
     HMLOG har on (t.ORIGIN = 25) and (t.REFERENCESID = har.ID) left join
     VESSEL va on (t.ORIGIN = 25) and (har.VESSELID = va.ID) left join
     CARGO_BOL bl on (t.ORIGIN = 26) and (t.REFERENCESID = bl.ID) left join
     HMLOG hbl on (t.ORIGIN = 26) and (bl.HMLOGID = hbl.ID) left join
     VESSEL vb on (t.ORIGIN = 26) and (hbl.VESSELID = vb.ID) left join
     CONTAINERLOG cl on (t.ORIGIN = 27) and (t.REFERENCESID = cl.ID) left join
     HMLOG hcl on (t.ORIGIN = 27) and (cl.HMLOGOUTID = hcl.ID) left join
     VESSEL vc on (t.ORIGIN = 27) and (hcl.VESSELID = vc.ID) 
where (t.ID = 269017)
```

But I'm unsure if this will work under all circumstances (I've never used constants in a join before) or if there is still a better way to do what I want.

Comment: A case expression is used to control which value will be returned in a column. You can't use it like this to somehow be multiple columns. You will need to split this into the 4 columns instead of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT T.ID
      ,T.TRANSACTIONNUMBER
      ,T.TRANSACTIONDATE
      ,A.ABBREVIATION
      ,A.NAME
      ,D.LINE1
      ,D.LINE2
      ,D.LINE3
      ,D.CITY
      ,D.[STATE]
      ,D.ZIPCODE
      ,TL.NAME COUNTRYNAME
      ,B.NAME BROKERNAME
      ,T.ORIGIN
      ,T.TRANSACTIONTYPE
      ,T.REFERENCESID
      ,T.POSTED
      ,T.DELETED
      ,T.PROFORMA
      ,T.REMARKS
      ,ABS(T.AMOUNT) AMOUNT
      ,C.CONVERSIONRATE
      ,C.ABBREVIATION CURRENCYABBR   
      ,COALESCE(H1.VESSELID, H2.VESSELID, H3.VESSELID) AS VESSELID
      ,COALESCE(H1.VOYAGENUMBER, H2.VOYAGENUMBER, H3.VOYAGENUMBER) AS VOYAGENUMBER
      ,COALESCE(H1.ARRIVALTIME, H2.ARRIVALTIME, H3.ARRIVALTIME) AS ARRIVALTIME
      ,COALESCE(H1.DEPARTURETIME, H2.DEPARTURETIME, H3.DEPARTURETIME) AS DEPARTURETIME
FROM [TRAN] T 
INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS A 
    ON (T.ACCOUNTID = A.ID)
INNER JOIN [ADDRESS] D 
    ON (T.MAILINGID = D.ID) 
INNER LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS B 
    ON (T.BRACCOUNTID = B.ID) 
INNER JOIN TYPES_LIST TL 
    ON (D.COUNTRY = TL.ID) 
INNER JOIN CURRENCY C 
    ON (T.ENTEREDCURRENCY = C.ID)
LEFT JOIN HMLOG AS H1
    ON H1.ID = T.REFERENCESID AND T.ORIGIN = 25
LEFT JOIN CARGO_BOL AS CB
    INNER JOIN HMLOG AS H2
        ON CB.HMLOGID = H2.ID
    ON CB.ID = T.REFERENCESID AND T.ORIGIN = 26
LEFT JOIN CONTAINERLOG AS CL
    INNER JOIN HMLOG AS H3
        ON CL.HMLOGOUTID = H3.ID
    ON CL.ID = T.REFERENCESID AND T.ORIGIN = 27
WHERE (T.ID = 269017)
```

Comment: Coalesce should return the first non-null parameter.  I think you can just do those statements like this:  ,COALESCE(H1.VESSELID, H2.VESSELID, H3.VESSELID) AS VESSELID